# insertions of record automatically while installing

Tags: custom-field, package, customsetting, install

I have created a product which contain a custom setting. In the custom setting it contain a record. I have the product as package and installed it into an new env but after installation
the user need to go and create record in custom setting to get the product working. I need to create records in custom setting automatically while installing. Is this possible to do? Is their any way please guide me.

Comment: Remember that after installation your app will still have no data in developer & config sandboxes. So while you can rely on post-install scripts etc you should also have some fallback plan (instruction what to fill in which cust. setting, maybe some "setup" page to which you'd redirect when config is incomplete and somebody tries to use your app...)

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is posssible using post install scripts. You can implement InstallHandler interface to specify the apex code that runs automatically after the package is installed. In the post install script you can create the custom setting record.

[InstallHandler interface documentation link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_install_handler.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, where campaign_builder__c is the custom setting. You can then set this class as the Post Install Script on the package as the post installation class

```
global class ExamplePostInstallClass implements InstallHandler {
  global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
    if(context.previousVersion() == null) {

    List<campaign_builder__c> kwc = new List<campaign_builder__c> ();

    //Account/Contact Fields
    kwc.add(new campaign_builder__c(
    Name = 'Chamber',
    Default_Value__c = 'All',
    Field_Name__c = 'Chamber__c',
    SFDC_Object__c = 'Contact'));

    insert kwc;

      }

      }
```